# How to scroll back to the top left using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

My problem is simple: I have a div container, with a property of `overflow:auto`, in mobile I see the scroll bar because my elements are out of the container, I can scroll to the right or left. I want that when I click an item in the top right, it gets placed in the head of the list (unshift), and the container goes back to its default position where the `scrollLeft` is 0. What I am doing is :

```
myElement.scrollLeft = 0;
```

But it is not working. This is the whole code I have:

```
function showDetails(i) {

  // Important 
  cdiscountHeaderOptions.scrollLeft = 0;

  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    let updatedData = data.filter(function (item) {
      return item.id - 1 !== i;
    });
    let selectedItem = data.filter(function (item) {
      return item.id - 1 === i;
    })[0];
    updatedData.unshift(selectedItem);
    renderData(updatedData);
  }

  detailsContainers.style.display = 'flex';

}
```

I tried also:

```
myElement.scrollTo(0,0);
```

But I got an error: scrollTo is not a function.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is place an empty div at the top `<div id="scrollToTop"></div>` of your HTML page and then in your js code, you can simply say `document.getElementById("scrollToTop").scrollIntoView();`

---

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Try putting a div where you want to scroll, make it position absolute so it's at a specific position, then you can use the `.scrollIntoView();` function

---

**UPDATED ANSWER**

`window.scrollTo(0,0)`

Comment: I said top left, meaning extreme left, not to the top Sir

Comment: well couldn't you still put a div where the scroll bar is at the beginning, that way when you say `.scrollIntoView();` it'll scroll into view which is the start position?

Comment: I will try it, and mark your answer as correct if it works

Comment: No, Not what I am looking for

Comment: Check my answer again, I updated it, this will go to the (0,0) of the window